# What was Shri Rama's response after the death of Kumbhakarna and Ravana?

Tags: ramayana, history, rama, ravana, kumbhakarna

I remember watching in one of the versions of *Ramayana* on TV that Shri Rama praised Kumbhakarna as a great warrior after he was killed. Did Shri Rama respond in any manner to their deaths? If so, what was the response?

Answer (score 4):

In Valmiki's Ramayana, I didn't get any reference That Rama praised Kumbhakarna after his death but when Ravana was slayed, his brother Vibhishana laments a lot, then Rama comforts him as:

> वदन्तं हेतुमद्वाक्यं परिदृष्टर्थनिश्चयम् |
>       रामः शोकसमाविष्टमित्युवाच विभीषणम् || ६-१०९-१४

```
Ravana did not die in battle, without making an effort. He has fallen in combat,
eventhough he was endowed with terrible prowess and exhibited extra ordinary
enthusiasm of a very exalted type and remained confident throughout.
```

> नायं विनष्टो निश्चेष्टः समरे चण्डविक्रमः |
>       अत्युन्नतमहोत्साहः पतितोऽयमशङ्कितः || ६-१०९-१५

```
There is no occasion to grieve for him having fallen into death in the battle-field
and by whom the development of his country was wished for, while remaining steadfast
in the duty of Kshatriya the warrior.
```

> नैवं विनष्टाः शोच्यन्ते क्षत्रधर्मव्यवस्थिताः |
>       वृद्धिमाशंसमाना ये निपतन्ति रणाजिरे || ६-१०९-१६

```
There is no occasion to grieve for his having been brought under the sway of death
by whom intelligent as he was, all the three worlds including indra were frightened.
```

> येन सेन्द्रास्त्रयो लोकास्त्रासिता युधि धीमता |
>       तस्मिन् कालसमायुक्ते न कालः परिशोचितुम् || ६-१०९-१७

```
In the past, none has ever been exclusively victorious in a combat. A hero either
has been killed by his adversaries or had killed the enemies in battle.
```

> नैकान्तविजयो युद्धे भूतपूर्वः कदाचन |
>       परैर्वा हन्यते वीरः परान्वा हन्ति संयुगे || ६-१०९-१८

```
Such is the destiny proclaimed by the ancients, as highly esteemed for a warrior.
A warrior killed in battle, does not deserve to be mourned. Such is the
ascertainment of the sacred scriptures.
```

Comment: And , according to this, Ravana did wish for the development of his country, the opposite is stated at many places

Comment: Lets see if someone answers in context of Kumbhakarna

Comment: Yes I am also waiting for the same